# rails mongo query based on BSON::ObjectId foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

`Mongodb` and `rails`

`Parent` object `has_many :children`

`Child` has a `parent_id` of class `BSON::ObjectId`

```
Child.first.parent_id
=> BSON::ObjectId('59031cd92936094d04000d31')
```

I can not find the `Parent` with that `_id`

```
Parent.where(_id: '59031cd92936094d04000d31').first
 => nil
```

The `Parent` object looks like this

```
 => #<Parent _id: 5a959865c8aedf03c1000007, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, type: nil, starts_at: nil, children_hash: nil>
```

Comment: `'59031cd92936094d04000d31'` and `BSON::ObjectId('59031cd92936094d04000d31')` are different things and I remember Mongoid sometimes automatically converting strings to `BSON::ObjectId`s and sometimes not. Not sure about the current behavior.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks a lot for your support. I am in debt

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if that was the problem, I just took a guess based on experiences from a few years ago. I used to batch a `to_bson_id` method into `String` and `BSON::ObjectId` so that I could say `M.where(some_id: whatever.to_bson_id)` and not have to worry about the type issues all the time.

Comment: @muistooshort `parent_id = Child.where(:parent_id.nin => [nil]).first.parent_id.to_s` returns `=> "59031cd92936094d04000d31"` and `Parent.where(_id: parent_id ).first` returns `=> nil`, maybe this test case does not work. thanks a lot ! I am a little bit in trouble right now and I don't know mongo

Comment: But what about `Parent.where(_id: BSON::ObjectId(parent_id))`? Or leaving off the `to_s` call on `parent_id = Child.where(....)`?

Comment: @muistooshort You are right, I needed to use `_id`. `Parent.where(_id: BSON::ObjectId('59031cd92936094d04000d31;).first` works, but the problem was the record. I found another record `object = Child.where(:parent_id.nin => [nil]).last.parent_id` and then I was able to get the `parent =  Parent.where(_id: object).first`. I usually get to read more before asking on SO, but now I can't.